# Regex is not working properly with sed but works in regex101

Tags: regex, sed, regex-group

I am just trying to strip everything before the first occurance of a single space character from each line.
Eg.`50G This is a Test (0000) 1234p (String).ext` should become `This is a Test (0000) 1234p (String).ext`

So i am using this simple regex - `^.+?\s(.*)` whereby i am just trying to wrap everything after the first space character in a group and then trying to substitute the whole match with the 1st group

Now this problem is that its working well in regex101 - https://regex101.com/r/1dAUcO/1
but when i try the same regex in terminal with sed , it returns a different output . Here's the sed command - `echo "50G This is a Test (0000) 1234p (String).ext" | sed -E 's|^.+?\s(.*)|\1|g'`

Comment: Using regex101, you really have to pay attention to the "flavor"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's|^.+?\s(.*)|\1|g
```

Where your intention of `.+?` is to make it a **lazy match** however `sed` (even in ERE mode) doesn't support lazy quantifier.

If you consider `perl` then it would work as is since `perl` has support for lazy quantifier:

```sh
echo "50G This is a Test (0000) 1234p (String).ext" |
perl -pe 's|^.+?\s(.*)|\1|g'

This is a Test (0000) 1234p (String).ext
```

---

**However** I would strongly recommend using `cut` for this as you don't have to bother about using a regex and this is what `cut` is made for:

```sh
echo "50G This is a Test (0000) 1234p (String).ext" |
cut -d " " -f2-

This is a Test (0000) 1234p (String).ext
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` regex flavor is POSIX that does not support lazy/non-greedy quantifiers.

You can use

```
sed -E 's|^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*||'
```

With GNU sed,

```
sed -E 's|^\S+\s*||'
```

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/JxZDnV):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="50G This is a Test (0000) 1234p (String).ext"
sed -E 's|^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*||g' <<< "$s"
## => This is a Test (0000) 1234p (String).ext
sed -E 's|^\S+\s*||' <<< "$s"
## => This is a Test (0000) 1234p (String).ext
```

You surely can use lazy quantifiers with `perl`:

```sh
perl -pe 's/^.+?\s//'
```

Note you do not need to capture the rest of the string to put it back with a backreference.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to just match the part to be removed and then substitute , it didn't struck me earlier .Can you just fix typo ```perl -pe 's/``` to ```perl -pe 's|``` . I tried to edit it but its saying there must be a minimum 6 character change to propose a change

Comment: @Sachin Thanks for letting know, I was already helping someone else when adding last minute changes to the answer. I'd rather use the "default" (most commonly used) slashes here as there are no slashes in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` code, you could try following too.

```
awk '
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/\([^)]*\)/){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$(i-1) OFS $(i)
    }
  }
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  val=""                  ##Nullifying val here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){     ##Traversing through all fields of current line here.
    if($i~/\([^)]*\)/){   ##Checking if current field is like (...) then do following.
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$(i-1) OFS $(i)  ##Creating val which has current and previous field value in it, keep appending its value to it.
    }
  }
  print val               ##Printing val here.
}
'  Input_file             ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```